# Good Windows 8 Mouse Input methods?

Tags: c#, input, windows-8, touch, mouse

I'm making a Windows 8 store app, and I discovered the following lovely code snippet:

```
while (TouchPad.IsGestureAvailable)
{
    GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();

    switch (gesture.GestureType)
    {
        case GestureType.Tap:
            //.. do something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

The horrible-ness of dealing with touch input has been solved by Microsqft and there are a ton of gestures available (besides just Tap) to stick in the switch above.  And why shouldn't this be Microsoft's job?  They're making an OS after all.

So, the question is: is there an equivalent to this for mouse input?  I'd like to, at least, deal with clicks and drags.  I realize mouse input is not that complicated, and I can take care of everything I need by looking at `Mouse.GetState()` in the update loop, but if there's a nice solution as in the above, I'd much rather do that.  Google is leaving me dry but I don't believe it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suspect that a click and a tap are the same thing.

Comment: You might suspect that, but if I click, it doesn't trigger the above switch block.